# Unable to start user profile synchronization service on sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm unable to start user profile synchronization service on sharepoint 2013 on premise.When I start the the service,under service account name and password section,account name shown as (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) and unable to change the value.How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Was User Profile service working properly or you have created new?

Comment: Service stoped and I'm unable to start it from sharepoint central administration.Requires password for (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) account.And unable to change the account even if I created a new one.

Comment: can you check in services, "Forefront Identity Manager"  service is running or not?

Comment: Nope,it's not started.And I'm unable to start it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the issue due to "Forefront Identity Manager" stopped. To start this service please follow below steps:

- Go to Central Administration. Click on "Manage services on server" under "System Settings".
  [image: Mange service on server]
- Now you can see the configured service list. Go to User Profile service and start it.
  [image: User profile start]
  When it start, check in services "Forefront Identity Manager". It will be started.

But you can't change User Profile Manage account once its configured. you need to delete it and create it once again. Please see below links for reference:

[MSDN link - User profile create](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721052.aspx)

[setup user profile service](http://jaxsharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/08/setup-and-start-sharepoint-2013-user.html)

Comment: User profile service is started.but I'm unable to start the user profile synchronization service right under that.this requires password for NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICES

Comment: Go to "Manage services on server" under "System Settings". you can see user profile synchronization service just under user profile service. Start this service. Once this service is started (might take few minutes to start), you will be able to start it.

Comment: When I click start,it redirect to user profile synchronization service page and under service name and password section account name shown as NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICES and it cannot be change.text field disabled.And it requires password for that account.All I want to do is synchronize the active directory to create staff profile

Comment: Try creating a new user profile with different user account then NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICES.

Comment: Okay.I'll try.Is there anyway to pm you?

Comment: You can post your query on stack overflow